# How to automatically take a picture without pressing the phototaken button on the imagepickercontroller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, api, uiimagepickercontroller

In my project, I need to take pictures automatically every one minute. But I can't find out any solutions.

This is the code which I implemented but it doesn't work...

I used a NSTimer to call up the camera to take pictures every 4 sec. And I only need the takepic

```
//This method is all for the time setup. You can ignore it.

-(NSDate *)userInfo {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [[[NSDate alloc]init]autorelease];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString);   

return date;    
}


- (void)targetMethod:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
   NSDate *startDate = [self userInfo];

   //newly changed lines.
   UIImagePickerController *myPicker;
   [myPicker takePicture];
   NSLog(@"Timer started on %@", startDate);

}


- (IBAction) showCameraUI {


   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                                 target:self
                               selector: @selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:[self userInfo]
                                repeats:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution.

I use the

```
 AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
```

to take pictures automatically.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer   
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

It is pretty simple and thank you @sch all the same for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

You can call the method [`- (void)takePicture;`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW24) of `UIImagePickerController` to take a picture programmatically. You can call it every one minute using a timer for example.

**Edit**

You should display the camera interface first (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406-SW3)). You can do this in the method `showCameraUI`. You should also keep a reference to the created `UIImagePickerController`.

```
- (IBAction) showCameraUI
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
    // create and display picker

   self.imagePicker = imagePicker;
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                             target:self
                           selector: @selector(targetMethod)
                           userInfo:nil
                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)targetMethod
{
    [self.picker takePicture];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for help. But I can't make it run successfully. Could you read my lines and give me some advise? I am new in objective-c, so ...

Comment: Can you describe what's the behavior you have now? Is `targetMethod:` executed? Are you sure `picker` is not `nil` when you execute `targetMethod:`?

Comment: I am sure targetMethod: can run because if I implemented the UIImagePickerController view, it can come out periodically. But if I implemented only

Comment: It's simple to verify, put a breakpoint at the line `[picker takePicture];` and see if the debugger stops there. Also check that picker is not `nil`.

Comment: Yes, I did as you said and it is nil... Then I changed the code but the program received EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the  [picker takePicture];

Comment: when I added the (gdb) po myPicker, it shows
0x3556f00f does not appear to point to a valid object.

Comment: @katielu see my edited answer. I hope it will show you how to correctly implement this.

Comment: Is the answer changed by you or you just edited my code in the question part? Because I changed my question several minutes ago without noticing that you have already changed some of the codes.

Comment: @katielu - I only changed my post. Check it and see if that help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but the piker function has a property  takePicture

```
double delayInSecondse = 3.0;
dispatch_time_t epopTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSecondse * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(epopTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
  [picker takePicture];
});
```