# Capturing image programatically in swift 2.0

Tags: ios8, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I am new in swift 2.0. i want to capture image programmatically and save it.Means when camera show then image capture automatically within 3 second without pressing button.

Comment: May be this will be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362785/how-to-automatically-take-a-picture-without-pressing-the-phototaken-button-on-th

Comment: Finally i get the solution from following link http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Finlly i get the solution ...
http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Use **takePicture** picture method Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html

Answer (score 0):

Use UIImagePickerController for capturing the image.
see below link : 
https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/